# Как поставить элементы ::before на списке li

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как выровнять мои элементы `before` от текста?

```css
ul li {
  .source_sans_reg();
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul .li_1::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Cup.png);
}

ul .li_2::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Mouse.png);
}

ul .li_3::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Energy.png);
}

ul .li_4::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Speedometer.png);
}


}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_1">Awesome design</li>
  <li class="li_2">Fully responsive</li>
  <li class="li_3">Retina ready</li>
  <li class="li_4">Tons of features and easy to use</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно вот так. На каждое изображение можно прописать свои `top` и `left`. Но без конкретный изображений сложно предугадать, что именно там у вас.

```css
ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 2.2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: .7em;
  left: 0;
}

ul .li_1::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Cup.png);
}

ul .li_2::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Mouse.png);
}

ul .li_3::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Energy.png);
}

ul .li_4::before {
  content: url(../Img/device/Speedometer.png);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_1">Awesome design</li>
  <li class="li_2">Fully responsive</li>
  <li class="li_3">Retina ready</li>
  <li class="li_4">Tons of features and easy to use</li>
</ul>
```